# Find all installed modules QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm creating app which ui is defined in json, from which i instatiate components in qml files from C++. But i would be glad if users can use built-in qml types.

1. Is there some way to find what qml modules (mainly visible components, but listing of all qml modules is huge plus) are installed in system?
2. Is there other solution for this problem. I'm thinking like create qml string manually, but what about imports?

Any other tips will be apreciated.

Comment: *"what qml modules are installed in system?"* sounds quite system specific. Are you thinking of Linux OSes with Qt installed by the package manager, or what? You could add relevant text and tags.

Comment: Also, why do you do it this way? Why don't you define the UI with... QML directly? It's quite JSON-like after all.

Comment: @hyde for first question. Qml isntalls all modules in Qml_import_path directory (even built_in types are installed this way). Installing qml module means creating qmldir file and qml file or compiled c++ with qml module into same directory. It can be then found by qml compiler and used in qml files. For second question i'm not the one creating ui. Users will be able to create ui themselfs from json (i dont want for my user to be programmers and teach them qml)

Comment: Then wouldn't simply getting a directory listing of the module directory work?

Comment: yes but only for modules defined from qml, but some qml types (rectangle, button etc) are compiled into c++ library (.so objects) ... but this gave me idea i might use qmldir files.

Comment: Such problems are usually an indication of improper application architecture. You should either refused to use JSON in this way and change it to regular QML or leave everything as it is and so the complexity of using this solution increases significantly. I already passed this way ...